# Can I use NSISO8601DateFormatter to parse an ISO-8601 string?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, foundation, iso8601

Foundation in macOS 10.12 has a new class, `NSISO8601DateFormatter`, which claims to be able to parse ISO-8601, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use it.

It takes a `.formatOptions`, which it says is used for parsing, too.  Isn't the whole point of ISO-8601 that it's an unambiguous format?

For example, this works:

```
let f = ISO8601DateFormatter()
f.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
f.date(from: "2018-11-26")  // a Date
```

but this ignores the time:

```
let f = ISO8601DateFormatter()
f.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
f.date(from: "2018-11-26T18:07:13Z")  // a Date but wrong
```

If I add `.withFullTime`, this works, but then the first example fails.

How do I parse ISO-8601 with NSISO8601DateFormatter?  Do I need to first pre-parse it on my own to figure out what sub-format of ISO-8601 it uses?

Comment: All date formatters are based on concrete date formats, either literally or with specific format options. They cannot detect multiple date formats. Maybe `NSDataDetector` is what you are looking for.

Comment: vadian: Is there a way to request that `NSDataDetector` treat its input as ISO-8601?  In my testing, there are many sub-formats that NSDataDetector doesn't seem to recognize at all.  Without context (i.e., knowing it's ISO-8601), there's many that don't necessarily look like dates.  The `NSDataDetector` docs even warn not to use it for ISO-8601.

Comment: If `NSDataDetector` doesn't cover all cases an alternative is Regular Expression and pattern matching.

Comment: I guess I could, if I wanted to do a bunch of date math myself.  Or I could use literally any other ISO-8601 parser in the world, because in 25 years of programming this is the first one I've ever seen that requires the user to specify the format.

Comment: If this is truly impossible with NSISO8601DateFormatter, then I confess I don't understand the purpose of this class. NSDateFormatter could already parse and format arbitrary dates, when supplied with the format ahead of time.  There's really nothing "ISO-8601" about it.

Comment: Most of the ISO-8601 dates appear in standard format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. This is also the standard format of `ISO8601DateFormatter`

Comment: You could always initialize two date formatters, and if the first one fails, use the second.